# min with over, without group by: returns unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, aggregate-functions

I have the following query:

```
SELECT      ContractNr
,           SequenceNr
,           DurationBeginDate 
,           MIN(DurationBeginDate) OVER(PARTITION BY contractnr ORDER BY SEQUENCENR ASC) mindurdat
FROM        AccountContract
WHERE       ContractNr = 768
```

which returns the following result:

```
ContractNr  SequenceNr DurationBeginDate            mindurdat
768         1          2008-03-08 00:00:00.0000000  2008-03-08 00:00:00.0000000
768         2          2008-06-08 00:00:00.0000000  2008-03-08 00:00:00.0000000
768         3          2008-09-08 00:00:00.0000000  2008-03-08 00:00:00.0000000
768         4          2008-12-08 00:00:00.0000000  2008-03-08 00:00:00.0000000
768         5          2007-06-08 00:00:00.0000000  2007-06-08 00:00:00.0000000
```

Which is not what I expected, what I want for the `mindurdat` field is the `DurationBeginDate` corresponding to the lowest `SequenceNr`. In other words, for all these records it should be `2008-03-08 00:00:00.0000000`
I don't understand why the last record in this example keeps the original `DurationBeginDate`.

I know I can get the right result with a sub-query, but I'd like to keep things efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use order by in a sum, min, max, etc... you get a running aggregate.  So it's doing exactly what it's designed to.  You can do what you want with a subquery or a join:

```
-- Join
SELECT
    ac.ContractNr
    , ac.SequenceNr
    , ac.DurationBeginDate 
    , ao.DurationBeginDate FirstDurationBegin
FROM
    AccountContract ac
LEFT JOIN
    accountcontract ao
    ON 
        ao.contractnr = ac.contractnr
        AND 
        ao.sequencenr = 1
WHERE
    ac.ContractNr = 768

-- outer apply
SELECT
    ac.ContractNr
    , ac.SequenceNr
    , ac.DurationBeginDate 
    , aor.DurationBeginDate FirstDurationBegin
FROM
    AccountContract ac
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT 
            ao.DurationBeginDate
        FROM 
            AccountContract ao
        WHERE
            ao.contractnr = ac.contractnr
            AND 
            ao.sequencenr = 1
    ) aor
WHERE
    ac.ContractNr = 768
```